# Syntax Error in Line 1 of Python on Mac: python 3.3.2

Tags: python, macos, syntax, python-3.x

I am having trouble because the syntax of my Python3 code is just fine. I just downloaded python 3.3.2 on my Mac 10.6.8.

Here is my code in IDLE and then my TERMINAL error message. When I run the program through IDLE, the syntax error message highlights the second "3" in python 3.3.2. What is going on??

IDLE:

```
Python 3.3.2 (v3.3.2:d047928ae3f6, May 13 2013, 12:45:22) 
[GCC 4.2.1 (Apple Inc. build 5577)] on darwin
Type "copyright", "credits" or "license()" for more information.
>>> print("Hello")
Hello
>>>
```

TERMINAL ERROR MESSAGE:

```
File "hello.py", line 1
Python 3.3.2 (v3.3.2:d047928ae3f6, May 13 2013, 12:45:22) 
         ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
```

Comment: You should not have the garbage at the start of your file; it was produced by Python when you started running it. Just start with the line `Print("hello")` as your first line.

Answer (score 1):

Put only the line:

```
print("Hello")
```

into `hello.py`.

Answer (score 1):

I guess your script contains the line:

```
Python 3.3.2 (v3.3.2:d047928ae3f6, May 13 2013, 12:45:22)
```

it should be only

```
print("hello")
```

or even better

```
#! /usr/bin/env python
print("hello")
```